# Should I use AcceptEx() or WSAAccept()?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, network-programming, overlapped-io

I am using Overlapped IO, I want to accept client connections using a blocking call, the same way I do with a normal `accept()`. I am not sure but I think that `AcceptEx()` does not block, while `WSAAccept()` does. So is `WSAAccept()` similar to `accept()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`accept()` and `WSAAccept()` will both block unless you've used `ioctlsocket` to set the listener to non-blocking mode. So you could use either of those to accept a client while blocking.

However you'll gain more control if you use `WSAEventSelect` to register an event against `FD_ACCEPT` on your listener. Your event will be set when a client is ready to be accepted without blocking.

You could then combine this event with, say, a timeout or another event that you can signal if you want to cancel the listen (e.g. on application exit) in a call to `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use a blocking call?

If you're using I/O Completion Ports then the best way to handle connection establishment is to use `AcceptEx()` and not wait for data along with the connect. The reason for this is that using `AcceptEx()` means that you don't need a separate thread to deal with connection establishment (i.e. a normal "accept loop") which reduces unnecessary context switches.

The 'accept and read data' option of `AcceptEx()` can open you up to a denial of service attack if connections connect and do not send data, and it's hard to guard against it unless you add a housekeeping thread which defeats the purpose of using `AcceptEx()` in the first place...

Comment: "The 'accept and read data' option of `AcceptEx()` can open you up to a denial of service attack" Then why should I use `AcceptEx()`?!

Comment: You should use it because it removes the need to have a dedicated accept thread and all the resulting (and pointless) context switching.

Comment: But you said "it can open you up to a denial of service attack".

Comment: Only if you also wait for data. You can use AcceptEx() and supply a buffer that will ONLY contain the addresses and not supply room for data and that works just as an overlapped accept and has no DOS issues.